# Would software RAID0'ing SSDs help or hinder maximization of useful CPU work throughput?

Tags: linux, raid, ssd, optimization, iowait

My question is in the title... here is some background:

[OS is Linux.]

[**UPDATE:**  The contents of this RAID0 is redundant (sync'd from SCM).  I am not worried about the increased risk of data loss.]

[**UPDATE 2:** Practically, I'm likely splitting hairs here.  But in addition to trying to solve a practical problem, I'm wanting to improve/confirm my understanding of the theoretical.]

I have an automated build server that I use to compile the source code of a very large project, and I am looking to minimize my build times.   I figure that the best possible build times will happen when the machine stays CPU-bound for the entire duration of the build (i.e., all cores loaded at 100%, the whole time.)  This is of course an idealized goal that can only be approached asymptotically.

I can tell from the behavior of the build (mostly, watching the output of mpstat) that the greatest enemy of my goal is %iowait.  There are times when I see a non-negligible %idle, and I consider that a modest failure of the kernel's scheduler, and/or small inefficiencies in Make's ability to parallelize the build.  But this is generally not big enough for me to worry about.  On the other hand, %iowait quite frequently gets seriously oversized... and my CPU load drops dramatically.  I believe this usually happens when some threads are trying to link up (write) large libraries to the (software-controlled[*]) RAID0 while other threads are trying read source code.

(Please ignore for the moment the fact that I can move the output writes to a different volume & controller than the source code.  That is planned.)

I am considering switching to SSDs.   But in that case, I think it is probably best to abandon the software RAIDing[*] of the drives.   My intuition is: the access times of the SSDs are so quick, and the transfer times so fast, that a simple LVM of 4 SSDs will squash my %iowaits to near-nothing, and my cores will then be constantly pegged, doing the maximum amount of useful work.

... In which case, software control of 4 RAIDed SSDs would needlessly increase my %sys, leaving less for %user.  My cores would still be pegged, but there would be less "useful" work getting done.

Is my intuition on software-RAID0'ing SSDs correct, for this particular goal?

[*] BONUS QUESTION: There is a RAID controller on the motherboard, but my understanding is that it is just 'fake RAID', supplying volume management functions within the BIOS option ROM, but otherwise just software RAID.  So I don't use it.   But would a true hardware RAID controller even be helpful here?  It is clear I can peg my cores quite easily on this machine; I just can't sustain it.  I believe SSDs will mostly solve that stamina problem, and I find myself wondering if even a real hardware RAID controller can improve on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software RAID under Linux on modern hardware is fine... even with SSDs. It doesn't place a tremendous demand on your CPUs. Really.

Heck, with premium [Fusion-io solid-state drives](http://www.fusionio.com/products/iodrive2/), the recommended and common deployment scheme is to use software RAID.

I wouldn't worry about this at all.

Also see: [Do I need to RAID Fusion-io cards?](https://serverfault.com/questions/523278/do-i-need-to-raid-fusion-io-cards)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I can certainly see using software RAID on SSDs if your goal is to maximize data throughput.  Maximizing CPU work completion per unit of time is a slightly different goal, and theoretically speaking I suspect software RAID will work against it, even if negligibly.  (I admit being ignorant of the overhead cost for software RAID on EXT4.  I know it has to be small relative to total CPU, but possibly the same magnitude as SSD access times.)

Comment: Put another way: It seems typical access times for SSD is 100us.  Could the RAID part of the filesystem driver's ISR complete in substantially less time than that?  For spinning metal (10ms), certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have accepted @ewwhite's answer above, I wanted to come back and report on a slightly conflicting answer that I just discovered elsewhere on the web, that is based on empirical data:

> Our results from the testing showed a 16% increase in reads while
>   utilizing (2) SSDs in a RAID 0, with a 2% decrease in write
>   performance. The performance gains from the reads is substantial
>   enough to warrant utilizing the RAID 0 for most purposes, but if
>   you're running an application that performs more writes than reads you
>   may benefit more from using the data disks stand-alone instead of
>   going with the RAID 0 option.

From http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/configuring-a-software-raid-on-a-linux-general-purpose-cloud-server

(My RAID is reading more than writing, so @ewwhite's answer is still appropriate for my needs.)